# What is the IAM User Attributes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

In AWS IAM faq's they mentioned that "User attributes other than username not supported at this time". What is the actual meaning of this? We can attach the other attributes like policies to the user. Can anyone explain What is the exact meaning of this? Appreciate your help.....!

Answer (score 1):

User attributes are attributes about the person¹ associated with the IAM user -- informational attributes about the individual user, such as last name, first name, job title, telephone number, twitter handle, etc.

IAM doesn't provide a way to store information about the individual person that is associated with an IAM user.

---

¹*person:* An IAM user may not be associated with a person because you might, for example, create an IAM user for your application to use when accessing AWS services.  This is not considered a best practice, since [EC2 instance roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html), Lambda execution roles, and ECS container roles all allow your application to have access to valid but temporary IAM credentials that are automatically provided and rotated by the service, eliminating the need to store static credentials in code repos or on servers.